# How to get orignal ip of user even if he is using proxy

Tags: proxy

Question is clear from title, is there a way to track user even if he is using a proxy. The point is, am i secure enough to surf internet with proxy to hide myself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Advanced techniques for detecting a proxy/getting original IP](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20067/advanced-techniques-for-detecting-a-proxy-getting-original-ip) and [Tracing Proxy Easy or Hard for a Normal Website?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13451/tracing-proxy-easy-or-hard-for-a-normal-website)

Comment: I visited above mentioned link but unable to get any solution to hide myself online so `not the answer i was looking for`

Comment: Well, you should have asked a a better answer. You wanted to know ways to detect a user's IP. Now you want ways to hide your own IP. Bad question either way.

Answer (score 3):

Browser plugins are your greatest threat, particularly Flash and Java, they can be used to run code which will bypass proxy settings.

A website such as this can show you how anonymous you at the moment.
http://ip-check.info/?lang=en

Simple proxy servers are not particularly good at hiding users. I suggest you do further reading on the topic and investigate alternatives to proxy servers, particularly the Tor network.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_censorship_circumvention